# Creating a Newsticker

Tags: php, ipb, invision-power-board

I am using IPboard 4 and am trying to create a newsticker.
Currently it looks like this:

[image: What it looks like]

But, it should look like this:

[image: What it should look like]

The Problem is I cannot find any material on ipb on how to edit output. 
Basically what I want to achieve is that the Title of an article is displayed with the number of comments and the date as posted ago and that the articles are grouped by weekday.

The current Template code looks like this:

```
 {{if !empty( $topics ) }}
    <h3 class='ipsWidget_title ipsType_reset'>{$title}</h3>

    {{if $orientation == 'vertical'}}
        <div class='ipsPad_half ipsWidget_inner'>
            <ul class='ipsDataList ipsDataList_reducedSpacing'>
                {{foreach $topics as $topic}}
                    <li class='ipsDataItem{{if $topic->unread()}} ipsDataItem_unread{{endif}}{{if $topic->hidden()}} ipsModerated{{endif}}'>
                        <div class='ipsDataItem_icon ipsPos_top'>
                            {template="userPhoto" group="global" app="core" params="$topic->author(), 'tiny'"}
                        </div>
                        <div class='ipsDataItem_main'>
                            <div class="ipsCommentCount ipsPos_right {{if ( $topic->posts - 1 ) === 0}}ipsFaded{{endif}}" data-ipsTooltip title='{lang="replies_number" pluralize="$topic->posts - 1"}'>{expression="$topic->posts - 1"}</div>
                            {{if $topic->mapped('featured') || $topic->hidden() === -1 || $topic->hidden() === 1}}
                                <span>
                                    {{if $topic->hidden() === -1}}
                                        <span class="ipsBadge ipsBadge_icon ipsBadge_small ipsBadge_warning" data-ipsTooltip title='{$topic->hiddenBlurb()}'><i class='fa fa-eye-slash'></i></span>
                                    {{elseif $topic->hidden() === 1}}
                                        <span class="ipsBadge ipsBadge_icon ipsBadge_small ipsBadge_warning" data-ipsTooltip title='{lang="pending_approval"}'><i class='fa fa-warning'></i></span>
                                    {{endif}}
                                    {{if $topic->mapped('featured')}}
                                        <span class="ipsBadge ipsBadge_icon ipsBadge_small ipsBadge_positive" data-ipsTooltip title='{lang="featured"}'><i class='fa fa-star'></i></span>
                                    {{endif}}
                                </span>
                            {{endif}}
                            <a href="{$topic->url()->setQueryString( 'do', 'getNewComment' )}" title='{lang="view_this_topic" sprintf="$topic->title"}' class='ipsDataItem_title ipsType_break'>{wordbreak="$topic->title"}</a>
                            <br>
                            <p class='ipsType_reset ipsType_medium ipsType_blendLinks'>
                                <!-- span>{lang="byline_nodate" htmlsprintf="$topic->author()->link()"}</span><br -->
                                <span class='ipsType_light'>{lang="topic_started_date" htmlsprintf="\IPS\DateTime::ts( $topic->mapped('date') )->html()"}</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {{endforeach}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div class='ipsWidget_inner'>
            <ul class='ipsDataList'>
                {{foreach $topics as $topic}}
                    {template="row" group="global" app="forums" location="front" params="NULL, NULL, $topic, FALSE"}
                {{endforeach}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{endif}}
{{endif}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.